# How to call specific function from a class on anchor click using PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I knew that I can go with AJAX to do so but I don't know how to achieve that using AJAX, so can any one guide me how to achieve this thing ? I am using radium one click demo import library and I want to add a button in my theme options on that button click I want to import data ... here is full code of radium one click import library. This code is inside `radium-importer.php` file. Could not enter full code due to text limit.

Here is the code that runs importer inside radium import class:

```
<div class="radium-importer-wrap" data-demo-id="1"  data-nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('radium-demo-code'); ?>">

        <form method="post">
            <?php $this->intro_html(); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="demononce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('radium-demo-code'); ?>" />
            <input name="reset" class="panel-save button-primary radium-import-start" type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_text ; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="demo-data" />

            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="radium-importer-message clear">
                <?php if( 'demo-data' == $action && check_admin_referer('radium-demo-code' , 'demononce')){
                    $this->process_imports();
                } ?>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

So, If my HTML is like:

```
<a href="#" class="import">Import Demo</a>
```

Then how can I run above `process_imports()` function using AJAX or PHP ? Any one to guide me through please ?

Comment: Hi Laraib, Learn the language you use! Then you will know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some snippet code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="import">Import Demo</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.import', function(e){
        e.preventDefault;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            data: 'action=import_process', // Your parameter goes here
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,  
            success: function(response){
                // Your response 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP Code for function.php file**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_import_process', 'import_process');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_import_process', 'import_process'); // Allow front-end submission

function import_process(){
    // Your php code goes here
}
```

Comment: I am still unable to call my function :( down voter means ?

Comment: DId you get any error? Someone down vote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

First make your `<a>` to be `<a href="#" onclick="process_imports()" class="import">Import Demo</a>`

Then it's your ajax function.

```
function process_imports(){
$.ajax({
            url: "data.php",//file wich has importing porcess
            data: {id:theid},//describe your data here
            dataType: 'json',// type of data that will you get (JSON/HTML).
            type: 'POST',//sending type (POST/GET)
            success: function(data) {
               //do what you want to be
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: no I have no data either, I have to just run that PHP function which is living inside radium_import class ... just tell me how to run that function ?

Comment: still unable to achieve that goal? :(